# It's the discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have to proof that if I have $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\delta)$ two topological spaces, if every function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuos then $\tau$ is the discrete topology. I don't know what is the way to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't true. If $\delta$ is the trivial topology, then every function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous. $(X,\tau)$ is discrete if any only if (for *every* $(Y,\delta)$ and every $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is continuous.)

Comment: I can prove that if it' discrete implies continuous, but can't the other way!

Answer (score 3):

Let $U \subset Y$ be a nontrivial open subset of $Y$ (i.e., neither the empty set nor all of $Y$), with $u \in U$ and $v \in Y - U$, and let $S \subset X$ be any subset of $X$. Then continuity of the function $f: X \to Y$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} u & \text{ if } x \in S \\ v& \text{ if } x \notin S\end{cases}$$ witnesses the fact that $S$ is an open subset of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

You need $\delta$ to be a non-trivial topology. So there must be an open set $U\in\delta$ such that $U\neq \emptyset$ and $U\neq Y$.

Then select $y_1\in U$ and $y_2\notin U$, and for $B\subseteq X$ define $f_B(x)=y_1$ if $x\in B$ and $f_B(x)=y_2$ if $x\notin B$. Then $f_B$ is continous, so $f_B^{-1}(U)=B$ must be open in $\tau$.